# It it possible to convert DVDs to my iPad?

Tags: ios, file-conversion, dvd, movie

I was wondering if anyone could help me.

I've recently got myself a "new" iPad (aka iPad 3), and I was wondering if it was possible to convert DVDs **I own** in order to watch them on it?

(Let's set aside the legality discussion since A) laws vary based on jurisdiction and B) the Internet isn't a good place to get legal advice.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is a great tool for ripping DVDs and otherwise converting video.

The legal question is probably beyond the scope of this forum, but if you own the dvd and are only ripping it for your own personal viewing, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: RipIt also works well and is simpler. I use both.

Comment: FYI, some studios went as far as making sure that their DVD is not rip-able by Handbrake.

Comment: Agreed, RipIt is good too if you want to archive your DVD’s for reconversion later. Sometimes Handbrake can’t get past the copy protection on certain DVDs, that’s when RipIt comes in handy — it rarely fails.

Answer (score 2):

Django your profile indicates you are from the UK, so you presumably would be governed by the laws of that country. In the US the legal precedent for this sort of activity would be "[The Betamax case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Corp._of_America_v._Universal_City_Studios,_Inc.)", which established that Americans have the right under Fair Use to "time shift" TV shows to tape.

I've used Handbrake.  It makes a hugely complex process much more manageable, but it's not perfect.